# prestashop Order return hook doesn't work in back-office

Tags: prestashop

Does anybody knows which hook to use in Prestashop 8 back-office when returning an order? I tried using actionOrderReturn but it only works in front-office

It worked fine on front-office but i don't know what to use in admin now

Comment: you can check the hook hookActionOrderStatusUpdate

Comment: I did but it still didn't work, i have nothing in params

Comment: It worked when changing the order state but not when returning products

Comment: You should use https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/actionobjectclassnameupdatebefore/ using as ClassName OrderReturn.
Should be this hook: actionObjectOrderReturnUpdateBefore
Hope it helps